# Question's title attribute is not HTML encoded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

Question's title attribute is not HTML encoded.

Examples:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/456815?body=true&answers=true

```
 title: "Problems with HTML <marquee> tag"
```

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/2233564?body=true&answers=true

```
 title: "<Canvas>  contents as data?"
```

I found it when on my app i saw a scrolling word due to the `<marquee>` tag on the title :).

In a very remote way, this could be a problem, because afaik there are no constraints on question's title submission.
I could forge a question title (300 chars max) like:

> ```
> What this script <script>evil_script_that_steal_your_stackexchange_webapp_cookies();</script> does?
> ```

Comment: I have noticed that from long time, and I was thinking it is by-design :P (may be not), and encoding myself for following 3 chars `&`, `"`, `<` in order.

Comment: @S.Mark me too, just curious about it.

Comment: It seems this may have changed since 2010, as question 456815's title is now HTML-encoded: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=456815&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question titles aren't markdown, they're plain text.

Accordingly, if you're going to display them in HTML you shouldn't display them "raw".